Identifying SMD Capacitors marked "33 10u" and "47 5v"
There are 3 leaking capacitors that I am struggling to identify replacements for. They are the only faulty components of a VHS camera from 1989 I want to mess with. Right now the device simply shuts off when the record button is pressed, but everything else works (and worked about a year ago).
I've tried to find out what marking system is used, but so far I haven't found any that match. Note the other capacitors to the right marked "10 16A".
Sorry if this is obvious. Any help is appreciated


SMT electrolytic capacitor markings seem to be all over the place. See How to identify surface mount electrolytic capacitors?.

My guess is 33uF 10V and 47uF 5V. I have no reference for this particular marking, but it just makes the most sense to me. Also, the capacitors on the right are all 10uF 16V by this logic.

I would expect the 33 and 47 are the capacitance in uF. The other code may be voltage, but maybe not.
The pads look pretty accessible. I suggest measuring the voltage and picking a capacitor replacement that is higher in voltage rating, if it is possible to get to the board with power applied.

Thank you, I will try and test the capacitors that are not leaking and see if it confirms the format of uF Voltage
